# -2 for unupvote: is that correct?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes

Here's what happened: one of my answers got upvoted, so I noticed that big blue thing with `+10` on it in 'reputation' tab. After some time, I noticed that the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001741/what-is-the-difference-between-lists-and-arrays/14001751#14001751) got unupvoted - and saw +10/-10 in the reputation pane. Fair cop, nothing strange here, <del>citizens just move along!</del>.

Then I got home, opened the page - and here's what I got:

[image]

Well, not that I'm too unhappy with that... but the total reputation is clearly calculated the same way it was - no `+8` on my weights today, all the round numbers only.

Am I missing something here? I didn't hit reputation limit this day, obviously.

P.S. Yes, I'm really sure that when I was checking my profile at work (Chrome 30), it was `+10/-10` there - but I wish I could prove it.

Comment: It almost looks like it is mislabeled as an unupvote when it should be a downvote.

Comment: I don't remember the score's for that answer either, but I think it got its two downvotes at its beginning - and not a single one today. Also, downvote would have surely adjusted my total rep - but it's still divisible by 10, as was yesterday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got an upvote on that question on Dec 22, 2012, after you reached the cap and were downvoted once. That vote gave you +2 reputation. In fact, you got *two* such +2 votes that day:

[image]

The question has been edited shortly after the first +2 vote (09:57 and 10:00 respectively), unlocking that vote, and the voter now *undid* the upvote.

Comment: Beat me to it! :-)

Comment: Argh. The mystic cap strikes again. ) Will accept in 8 minutes.

Comment: Not valid on odd Tuesdays during a full moon, unless you stand on your head, wiggle your toes and scream "STELLA!"

Comment: That circle is only pseudo-freehand masquerading as a true freehand circle. A sheep in wolf's clothing it is.

Comment: It is freehand drawn with a trackball, you insensitive clod!